# can not mirror the nav2_bringup package

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, python3

I want to make some modifications to the [nav2_bringup](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/README.md) package. Therefore, I just copied the nav2_bringup package put it in the workspace and ran the [Turtlebot 3](https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#getting-started) simulator. The following error occurred. Without copies, no errors, all work fine.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/README.md

`[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): cannot import  name 'PushROSNamespace' from 'launch_ros.actions' (/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-  packages/launch_ros/actions/__init__.py)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull your config file from the humble branch, not the main branch (which targets Rolling). Your issue is API updates made to more recent distributions are not in Humble. Mirror from the humble branch instead.

Comment: Yeap, pull did not help me, however, I coped from the installed nav2 package , and then all went fine. Thank youu